# Change latlong to UTM coordinates. Error:must be real number, not str.

Tags: pandas, dataframe, coordinates, geopandas

I have a problem to change my `csv` data from Latlong (degree) to UTM coordinates.
this is example data:

```
Date        Time    Latitude  Longitude
23/08/2018  9:00:00 -5.1661   119.4543
23/08/2018  9:00:01 -5.166    119.4544
23/08/2018  9:00:02 -5.1659   119.4544
23/08/2018  9:00:07 -5.1657   119.4546
23/08/2018  9:00:42 -5.162    119.4567
23/08/2018  9:00:43 -5.1614   119.4567
23/08/2018  9:00:44 -5.16     119.4548
```

and I tried this way to change the coordinate

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
s = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])])
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df[['Date','Time']], geometry=s) 
geo_df.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} 
geo_df = geo_df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32750'})
geo_df
```

but I got `TypeError: must be real number, not str`

any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show `df.head()` after reading the csv? Further question: on what line if the error raised? Only on the `to_crs` line, or already when creating the GeoSeries ? I suspect the csv file is not read in correctly, and the longitude/latitude columns are actually strings.

Comment: I get an error on the second line when I tried GeoSeries. yeah, the coordinates columns were read as strings.

Comment: So that solved the question?

Comment: I have to check again my data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Latitude, df.Longitude)]
df = df.drop(['Latitude', 'Longitude'], axis=1)
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32750'})
```

check [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174159/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-geodataframe) and [here](http://geopandas.org/projections.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I still got an error. I have 4 millions rows of this data.

Comment: @Arief there might be something wrong with the data, but I am not sure!